# How to find transformation from the upper half plane into the right half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations, mobius-transformation

> Find the general form of the linear transformation which transforms
>
> the upper half plane into the right half plane.

In my notes I have a Mobius transformation from the upper half plane to the unit circle $T(z)=e^{i\theta_0}\frac{z-z_0}{z-\overline z_0}$.

Also another transformation from the unit circle to the upper half plane $T(z)=(1-i)\frac{z-i}{z-1}$.

But I do not know how to construct the possible composition transformation from upper half plane into the right half plane.

Could someone help please?

Any hint?

Comment: How about you just rotate the plane?

Comment: @quid Ok, Am I going to use this transformation $T(z)=e^{i\theta_0}z$ then?.

Comment: Yes.  And what is $\theta_0$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork it's the angle of rotation, the principal argument

Comment: Ugh... what is the *value* of $\theta_0$ to fulfill the requirements of your problem?  Is $\theta_0 = 0.99746333$?  Or $\theta_0 = \pi^2/9.44$?  Or maybe another value?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork value? I never heard my professor talking about values of $\theta_0$. $\theta_0$ it's  arg(a), where T(z)=az+b and |a|=1

Comment: Yes, that's a good start. As David says, now you need to determine the angle. Maybe draw a picture to figure out the correct angle. Or consider  what will be the image of $z=1$?

Comment: Answer:  $\theta_0 = -\pi/2$.

Comment: All these comments seem to a address finding a single linear fractional transformation that fulfills the requirement, but the question asks for the general form.

Comment: @saulspatz yes that's right. Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I'd be glad to tell you if I knew how.  A Möbius transformation $T$ is of the form $$T(z) ={az+b\over cz+d}$$ where $ad-bc\neq 0,$ so the question apparently asks for conditions on $a,b,c,d.$  It looks easy if $c=0$ -- just a straightforward elaboration of  the answers given in the comments -- but I haven't been able to either handle the $c\neq0$ case or to prove that $c=0.$

Comment: It just struck me that your question asks for a "linear transformation," although you give examples of Möbius transformations in your discussion.  Ahlfors calls Möbius transformations "linear transformations" in his classic text, but I would say this is idiosyncratic.  When you says, "linear transformation" in this context, do you mean "Möbius transformation?"  If instead you mean linear transformation in the usual sense, $T(z)=az$ then the question is easy.

Comment: @saulspatz hmm I don't know if it refers to Möbius or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it.  The transformation $T$ must take the boundary of the upper half-plane to the boundary of the right half-plane.  That is, it must take the real axis to the imaginary axis.  If $$T(z)={az+b\over cz +d},\ ad-bc\neq=0,\tag{1}$$ we have that $x\in\mathbf{R}$ implies $$\Re\frac{(ax+b)\overline{(cx+d)}}{|cx+d|^2}=0\implies\Re(ax+b)\overline{(cx+d)}=0$$

Now for given, $a,b,c,d\in\mathbf{C},\ \Re(ax+b)\overline{(cx+d)}$ is a quadratic in $x$ that vanishes everywhere, so all the coefficients must be $0$. That is, 
$$\Re(a\overline{c})=\Re(a\overline{d}+b\overline{c})=\Re(b\overline{d})=0\tag{2}$$

Let us assume that $c\neq0.$  Then we may divide numerator and denominator in $(1)$ by $c$, or what is the same thing, we may assume that $c=1,$ so $(2)$ becomes 
$$\Re(a)=\Re(a\overline{d}+b)=\Re(b\overline{d})=0\tag{3}$$

From $c=1$ we have $T(-d)=\infty,$ but $\infty$ is on the imaginary axis so $d\in\mathbf{R},$ and from $(3),$ we have $\Re a=0$ and $\Re(ad+b)=0,$ so that $\Re b = 0.$  That is, 
$$T(z) = i\frac{\alpha z+\beta}{z+d}, \text { where } \alpha,\beta,d\in\mathbf{R}, \alpha d -\beta\neq0$$
which can obviously be re-written more symmetrically as 
$$T(z) = i\frac{\alpha z+\beta}{\gamma z+ \delta}, \text { where } \alpha,\beta,\gamma \delta\in\mathbf{R}, \alpha\delta-\beta\gamma\neq=0$$

However, this leaves open the possibility that $T$ maps the upper half-plane to the $left$ half-plane.

This leaves you with two things to do.  First, finish off the $c\neq0$ case.  (Hint: $\Re T(i)>0$.) Second, do the (easier) $c=0$ case.

I feel that there must be an easier way of seeing this, but I've not been able to find one.

Comment: Might be easier to start with the mapping of the upper half-plane to itself and then multiply by $-i$. From the formula for a linear-fractional transform mapping $z_1, z_2, z_3$ to $w_1, w_2, w_3$, we obtain that mappings of the real line to itself are given by $(a z + b)/(c z + d)$ with $a, b, c, d$ real. The condition that the direction is preserved is given by $T'(z) > 0$ for real $z$, or $a d - b c > 0$.

Comment: @Maxim T I don't have time to consider this closely just now, but on a quick read, it sounds goo. I'll think about it later.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I didn't know the book have answers.. I checked the answer and it's $w=-i(az+b)$

Comment: Do you know how was constructed?

Comment: Well, they're talking about linear transformation (actually affine transformations) not Möbius transformations.  This is just the $c=0$ case of the above.

Comment: What does the bold curly R mean?

Comment: @Isa The real part. $z=\Re z + i\Im z$

Answer (score 2):

Simple, rotating 90 degrees to the right:

$$ T(z) = -iz $$